# How to properly use the <more> tag on pages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

According to the forum in this article, [fixing the read more tag problem](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/fixing-the-read-more-tag-problem-in-wordpress-static-pages/), Mark Pasay has the same difficulty as I do in using this code snippet as a solution. `<?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>` But the author does not elaborate on how to use this properly. I am using a page template that is called in the WP admin. The `<!--more-->` is added in the text editor. Here is the code for the page template.

```
/*
    Template Name: new template
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="entry-content">

        <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>

        <?php the_content('read more'); ?>

        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div><!-- #post-## -->

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

The tag shows up in the browser but when clicked, it does not show the full post. 
On click, the URL changes from localhost/domain.com/page/ to localhost/domain.com/page/#more-481. 
The author explains that this is not being used properly because it is calling content of pageX from pageX. "This trick will only work when you are trying to display excerpts of pageX on pageY." Fair enough, but how is this done?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the read more tag?

Comment: I would like it to show the full post when clicked.